# php form not writing form data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I have to code below - updated

php code

```
    if(empty($_POST['formEmail'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your email</li>";
    }

    $varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {

        $db = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("tableName" ,$db);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('$varEmail')";

    mysql_query($sql);


echo "Details added";
$_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
 }

exit();


    }

function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

    return($value);
}
?>
```

form code

```
    <?php
if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
{
echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    }
    ?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<p>
<label for='formEmail'>Sign up to be notified when we go live!</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="formEmail" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varEmail;?>" />
</p>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I'm not getting any errors and as far as I can tell the syntax looks fine but its not putting the email information into the database. Anyone have an idea of whats going on? As a side note I am a newb to all php.

Comment: never ever inject `$_*` super globals in a query, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape all $vars whether they come from you or the user. Also `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is broken and should never be used.

Comment: @Johan, I dont know much about sql databases so what you said might as well be in latin. would you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain and here on why magic quotes are broken: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 6):

You've forgotten to run the query! Put

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

straight after

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('$varEmail')";
```

Make sure you run the `$_POST` variable through `mysql_real_escape_string` as well:

```
$varEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['formEmail']);
```

This will help protect you from [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**EDIT**

One more tiny thing, I guess you want to set the session variable `success` when the form has submitted successfully. to do that you'll need to move

```
echo "Details added";
$_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
```

within the same `if` structure as the SQL query is run, otherwise it will never be set

Comment: now I'm getting the error:  Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket      why would adding the mysql_real_escape be causing any problems?

Comment: @bjstone15, You need to **connect** to the database before using `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise it will give you that error.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    $db = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");
    if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
    mysql_select_db("tableName" ,$db);


    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO emails(email) VALUES ('%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($varEmail));
    $results = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: -1, a db called tablename is just weird and not addressing the SQL-injection hole is dangerous.

Comment: First of all, it is copied directly from his code. Second of all, he just needs to see that it is working before he addresses security. This is no reason to mark an answer down. I edited my response with a much better approach to dealing with security.

Comment: the name 'tableName' is not the name of the table but just something I was using for an example.

Comment: @bjstone15, I understood what you were doing. I'm not sure why people get so specific about these things that they mark down people who ask legitimate questions and those who give legitimate, next-step, answers. Feel free to mark me up if you find my answer helpful.

Comment: %s is a replace string. You can include them in your sprintf statement, but define them after the string. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for more info...but it is just a string-print-format (sprintf) which allows you to define a format and parameters to be formatted.